# HTTP GET request forbidden 403 error while using netcat

Tags: get, http-status-code-403, netcat

So, I have to get http://www.rssweather.com/wx/in/kanpur/wx.php with using netcat.

My code goes like this.

```
nc -v rssweather.com 80
GET http://www.rssweather.com/wx/in/kanpur/wx.php HTTP/1.0
GET http://www.rssweather.com/wx/in/kanpur/wx.php HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
```

And, the result-

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Date: Thu, 03 Sep 2015 12:41:08 GMT

Server: Apache

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html

charset=iso-8859-1

You don't have permission to access /wx/in/kanpur/wx.php
on this server.

Is there any way to overcome this Forbidden 403 error? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already connected to the webserver at `rssweather.com` so you must not specify the full URL in the GET request, just the path:

```
nc -v rssweather.com 80
GET /wx/in/kanpur/wx.php HTTP/1.0
<blank line with return>
```